# Set function to symbol

Tags: lisp

I have some problems with setting function to symbol. For example, I add some properties to symbol:

```
(putprop 'rectangle '10 'width)
(purprop 'rectangle '2 'height)
(putprop 'rectangle (* (get 'rectangle 'width) (get 'rectangle 'height)) 'square)
```

And when I type `(symbol-plist 'rectangle)` I get:

```
(SQUARE 20 HEIGHT 2 WIDTH 10)
```

But if I change height or value I get old square value:

```
(putprop 'rectangle 10 'height)
(symbol-plist 'rectangle)
```

How I can set function as symbol property? If I set property as lambda, `symbol-plist` gets me something like `#<Closure-square: #12345>`

Comment: You can [funcall](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm) the closure, and you can you use [symbol-function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_1.htm) to access to the function of a given symbol.

Comment: Yes, I can use funcall, but can you explain how I can use symbol-function?

Comment: Hmm I was wrong, I thought that we could manipulate properties
like symbols but the problem remains. We can't make a function which
returns a function and evaluate it immediately (without funcall). I
think that's because Common Lisp is a lisp-2 and not a lisp-1. i.e.
a symbol can have both a value and a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `symbol-function` to define aliases for functions with good but long names:

```
* (defun hello-world () (format t "Hello, World!~%"))
HELLO-WORLD
* (hello-world)
Hello, World!
NIL
* (setf (symbol-function 'hw) #'hello-world)
#<FUNCTION HELLO-WORLD>
* (hw)
Hello, World!
NIL
```

This is a function I have created for this:

```
(defun defalias (function alias)
  "Defines an alias for FUNCTION, so it can be called with ALIAS as well."
  (setf (symbol-function alias) function))
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the symbol's property to a lambda expression, does not automatically apply the that lambda expression every time other properties change (which is what I guess you want).

You could write a wrapper function that sets the symbol's `height` or `width` property and recalculates the the symbols `square` property.

Comment: Is there other ways, to get `square` value with current `width` and `height`? Can symbol have methods?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are using symbol properties for this problem in the first place?

Comment: Yes, this is task from my teacher :-) I can't find anything informatio n about this and thats why I ask it here

Comment: I'm interested in knowing exactly what the task is. The reason for this is that symbol properties are almost never used in the real world.